# How to find a file with spaces in the folder name in Microsoft Access SQL?

Tags: sql, ms-access, directory, path

I am trying to run a Microsoft Access Query using this SQL

```
SELECT * FROM tblMyClients IN 'C:\Data\Clients\Food Pantry Ver 2\DB\FoodPantryRemoteDB.accdb';
```

I am getting the error message "Could not find file..."

If I remove the spaces in the folder name the query works fine. But, removing the spaces is not an option.

What syntax can I use to make this work?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is correct, so either the file does not exist, or you could try with double-quotes:

```
SELECT * FROM tblMyClients IN "C:\Data\Clients\Food Pantry Ver 2\DB\FoodPantryRemoteDB.accdb";
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. The file does exist. If I remove the spaces it works fine on my computer, but with the spaces in the folder name Access cannot find the file because of the spaces. I have tried double quotes, I have tried combinations of multiple double quotes and single quotes. Removing the spaces on a client's computer is not an option.

Comment: That is weird. You code works flawlessly here with a spaced filename. Are you sure the spaces are true spaces and not some white-space character? Else, try to _link_ the table (`DoCmd.TransferDatabase acLink ... etc.`); then you can name the linked table as you like.

Comment: Thank you, Gustav. Yes, you are right it does work. For some reason it does not work on the D:\ drive. I have had this problem before with Access, it sees the D:\ drive as an argument. Thank you, again.